# Store cedentials for SharePoint file download c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sharepoint, vsto

I've been using `WebClient.DownloadFile` with `SharePointOnlineCredentials` to download a file from SharePoint but this requires credentials to be input by the user every time. I want the user to have to enter credentials only once when first using the application.

Should I be using/can I use something like oauth/graph? Or should I be looking at something like windows credential manager to store them securely.

Comment: If their credentials are the same as for logging into the computer, `System.Environment` or `System.Net` may have a namespace worth using. Otherwise- you could store them as global variables that are set by user one time. This will require the user to re-input their credentials on start up of the program and not require you to store them anywhere

Comment: Credentials manager is an option, but you’d need to have a way for the user to update those credentials when/if they change. Oauth would allow you to get permission from the user for your app to interact with SPO in a managed way, that is not coupled to the user’s credentials (and will mean you don’t need to store those).

Comment: @sasfrog thanks, I went with Oauth in the end